# Closed form vs methods based on gradient descent

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am a beginner to optimization. Could anybody give me a simple example to illustrate when I should use closed form and when I should use iterative methods like gradient descent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can find closed-form expression to solve your optimization problem go for it! But it is a very rare situation, that's way iterative methods has been developed.